# Missing values in groupby apply function

Tags: python, regression, pandas-groupby, python-xarray

I have a large dataset [time,lat,lon]. I want to regress a variable against time for each point in the grid, but using a for loop takes forever. I found that grouping the dataarray by lat/lon and applying a function reduces the computation time by a lot. I'm applying a function to a dataarray [time,lat,lon] that has been grouped by lat/lon. My end result would be [lat,lon]. Some grid points don't have any data all (np.nan). I want the function to return np.nan for such grid point, but I'm getting the following error:
**SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares**

Here's the code:

```
hus = ifile.hus

#stack lat and lon into a single dimension called allpoints 
stacked = hus.stack(allpoints=['lat','lon'])

# define a function to compute a linear trend of a timeseries
def linear_trend(x):
    x = x.dropna(dim='time')
    if len(x)==0:
        return xr.DataArray(np.nan)
    else:
        time = np.arange(len(x))
        pf = np.polyfit(time, x, 1)
        return xr.DataArray(pf[0])
    

trend = stacked.groupby('allpoints').apply(linear_trend)
trend_unstacked = trend.unstack('allpoints')
trend_unstacked
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-4e885325e9c4> in <module>
     13 
     14 # apply the function over allpoints to calculate the trend at each point
---> 15 trend = t.groupby('allpoints').apply(linear_trend)
     16 trend_unstacked = trend.unstack('allpoints')
     17 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/groupby.py in apply(self, func, shortcut, args, **kwargs)
    824             stacklevel=2,
    825         )
--> 826         return self.map(func, shortcut=shortcut, args=args, **kwargs)
    827 
    828     def _combine(self, applied, restore_coord_dims=False, shortcut=False):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/groupby.py in map(self, func, shortcut, args, **kwargs)
    809             grouped = self._iter_grouped()
    810         applied = (maybe_wrap_array(arr, func(arr, *args, **kwargs)) for arr in grouped)
--> 811         return self._combine(applied, shortcut=shortcut)
    812 
    813     def apply(self, func, shortcut=False, args=(), **kwargs):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/groupby.py in _combine(self, applied, restore_coord_dims, shortcut)
    833             combined = self._concat_shortcut(applied, dim, positions)
    834         else:
--> 835             combined = concat(applied, dim)
    836             combined = _maybe_reorder(combined, dim, positions)
    837 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/concat.py in concat(objs, dim, data_vars, coords, compat, positions, fill_value, join)
    133             "objects, got %s" % type(first_obj)
    134         )
--> 135     return f(objs, dim, data_vars, coords, compat, positions, fill_value, join)
    136 
    137 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/concat.py in _dataarray_concat(arrays, dim, data_vars, coords, compat, positions, fill_value, join)
    427     join="outer",
    428 ):
--> 429     arrays = list(arrays)
    430 
    431     if data_vars != "all":

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/groupby.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    808         else:
    809             grouped = self._iter_grouped()
--> 810         applied = (maybe_wrap_array(arr, func(arr, *args, **kwargs)) for arr in grouped)
    811         return self._combine(applied, shortcut=shortcut)
    812 

<ipython-input-9-4e885325e9c4> in linear_trend(x)
      8     else:
      9         time = np.arange(len(y))
---> 10         pf = np.polyfit(time, x, 1)
     11         # we need to return a dataarray or else xarray's groupby won't be happy
     12         return xr.DataArray(pf[0])

<__array_function__ internals> in polyfit(*args, **kwargs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py in polyfit(x, y, deg, rcond, full, w, cov)
    603         raise TypeError("expected 1D or 2D array for y")
    604     if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 605         raise TypeError("expected x and y to have same length")
    606 
    607     # set rcond

TypeError: expected x and y to have same length
```

​

Comment: Please provide a sample of the df. Ideally, a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's a large dataset so I don't know how to best provide an example. But I'm attaching the error message if that helps.